# Is there a way to capture permission change in Django Guardian?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-guardian

I would like to receive a signal after permission is changed on the object level. Django Guardian allows us to set object-level permissions. Based on the permission change, I'd like to perform some actions.

How to receive a signal on object level permission change?

Comment: How are you changing permissions?

Comment: I'm changing permissions through the Django Admin Site